# What is the best sensor to detect the movement

Tags: android, arduino

I'm working on an android application to detect the human movements like FRONT, BACK, RIGHT, and LEFT.
So suppose that your phone is in front of your face, if you move it to left the X axe should give some negative values and if you move it up the Y axe should give some positive values, what is the best sensor for this job?

I think accelerometer isn't good for this job.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [rotation vector](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR) or the [gyroscope](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#TYPE_GYROSCOPE), if your device has them.

You can't know if the person using the device is walking (in any direction), because sensors are only relative to the device. You should use position to do that.